# How to use AWK to reformat lines?

Tags: awk

How to use `AWK` to transform the lines of `linear format` to those of `tabular format`? e.g. to change the format of Ubuntu versions from:

```
13.10
Saucy
Salamander
14.04
Trusty
Tahr
14.10
Utopic
Unicorn
```

to:

```
13.10,Saucy,Salamander
14.04,Trusty,Tahr
14.10,Utopic,Unicorn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%3?",":"\n")}1' file
13.10,Saucy,Salamander
14.04,Trusty,Tahr
14.10,Utopic,Unicorn
```

Comment: Nice!  but does not completely work.. Got this output: http://pastebin.com/jhFRjbnW

Comment: It does work, the OP had just originally misled you by posting vague input and expected output that didn't make sense in the context of the rest of his question. He's since updated his question with sensible input and matching output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sed` for that:

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/,/g' input.txt
```

The command reads a line and appends two additional lines to the pattern buffer `N;N`. Then it replaces the newlines in between them by a `,` with `s/\n/,/g` .